# Are there any alternatives to Sigil?

Tags: ebook, epub, sigil

I have been using Sigil to edit epub (eBook format) files.  However, it is excruciatingly slow on Windows and Linux.  After doing some research, I found other people are complaining about it too.  After doing some research, I discovered that the slowness is due how it was developed.

I found eCub, but it isn't as feature rich as Sigil.  Are there other open source/free alternatives out there?

Comment: I would recommend against creating your own tags when they don't help with categorizing  your question.

Answer (score 1):

Right now?  If you don't like eCub or Jutoh, you don't have many options.

You *may* be able to press an HTML editor into doing the job, but you'll definitely want something that can handle a multi-page project, to make sure that cross file links don't get broken and that your CSS stays sane.  You'll also want to run the result through [FlightCrew](http://code.google.com/p/flightcrew/) (the ePub validator component of Sigil) to make sure your work is valid.

Another option, if you don't mind rounds of conversions, would be to convert to an OpenOffice document, modify in OOo or LibreOffice, and use [Writer2ePub](http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/en/project/Writer2ePub) to convert the result to an ePub file.

Answer (score 0):

Original answer:

There are two listed here: http://alternativeto.net/software/sigil/

What I was implying by the original:

I would suggest checking [alternativeto.net](http://alternativeto.net/software/sigil/). If/when another alternative becomes available that will probably be the fist/easiest place to find something usable. I would subscribe to the RSS feed for that app so you will be notified when something new becomes available. Since I'm not interested in that world I'm just going to point you to a resource you can use to find alternatives on your own.

Comment: As my question states, I already found eCub and didnt like it.  And Jutoh isnt free.  If you are going to answer a question, take the time to do it right.

Comment: @Keltari -- Looks like my down voted answer might prove useful after all. There is now 4 listed alternatives for the software you mentioned. Hope one of them works for you. Good luck! :)

Comment: @Keltari -- 6 listed now.... Cricket, Cricket, Cricket.